# How to implement sign in methods merging in flutter app using parse server?

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

in my mobile app i have 4 methods of login:

1. Normal sign in/log in using e-mail and password
2. [Google Sign In](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)
3. [Flutter Facebook Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth)
4. [Sign In With Apple](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple)

The problem is for example when I create my account using Google Sign In with email@example.com, then i log out and try to login using my Facebook account which is created with the same e-mail there's error. Summing up every single login function works independently.

I wonder if it's possible to handle this with cloud function?

Here's Flutter code:

```
 ///GOOGLE
  static Future<bool> signWithGoogle() async {
    // return false;
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn( scopes: ['email'] );

    GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    googleSignInAccount = account;
    if (account == null) return false;
    GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication = await account.authentication;

    String? email = _googleSignIn.currentUser!.email;

    final bool firstLogin = await isFirstLogin(email);
    ParseResponse response;

    if (firstLogin){
      response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
        'google',
        google(
            authentication.accessToken!,
            _googleSignIn.currentUser!.id,
            authentication.idToken!
        ),
        username: _googleSignIn.currentUser!.displayName,
        email: email,
      );
    }else {
      response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
        'google',
        google(
            authentication.accessToken!,
            _googleSignIn.currentUser!.id,
            authentication.idToken!
        ),
      );
    }


    if (response.success){
      return _setDeviceId(response.result);
    }else
      _handleError(response);

    return false;
  }

  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> googleForDataOnly() async {
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn( scopes: ['email'] );

    return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  }

  ///FACEBOOK
  static Future<bool> signWithFacebook() async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions: [
      'email',
      'public_profile',
      'user_location'
    ]);
    if (result.status == LoginStatus.cancelled) return false;

    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      if (result.accessToken == null) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: Translate.unknownError());
        return false;
      }

      final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();
      String? email = userData['email'];

      if (email == null || email.isEmpty){
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: Translate.emailPermissionRequired());
        return false;
      }

      final bool firstLogin = await isFirstLogin(email);
      ParseResponse response;

      if (firstLogin){
        response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
          'facebook',
          facebook(result.accessToken!.token,
              result.accessToken!.userId,
              result.accessToken!.expires
          ),
          email: email,
          username: userData['name']
        );
      }else {
        response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
          'facebook',
          facebook(result.accessToken!.token,
              result.accessToken!.userId,
              result.accessToken!.expires
          ),
        );
      }

      if (response.success) return _setDeviceId(response.result);
      else _handleError(response);

    }

    return false;
  }

  static Future<bool> facebookDataOnly() async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions: [
      'email',
      'public_profile',
      'user_location'
    ]);
    if (result.status == LoginStatus.cancelled) return false;

    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
      if (result.accessToken == null) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: Translate.unknownError());
        return false;
      }

     return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  ///APPLE
  static Future<bool> signWithApple() async {
    final AuthorizationCredentialAppleID credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email, AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName],
    );

    final String? email = credential.email;
    final String? name = credential.givenName;
    final String? famName = credential.familyName;
    String? userName;
    if (name != null && famName != null){
      userName = '$name $famName';
    }

    if (email == null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: Translate.invalidEmail());
      return false;
    }

    final bool firstLogin = await isFirstLogin(email);
    print(firstLogin);
    ParseResponse response;

    if (firstLogin){
      response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
        'apple',
        apple(
            credential.identityToken!,
            credential.userIdentifier!
        ),
        email: email,
        username: userName
      );
    }else {
      response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
        'apple',
        apple(
            credential.identityToken!,
            credential.userIdentifier!
        ),
      );
    }


    if (response.success){
      return _setDeviceId(response.result);
    }else {
      _handleError(response);
    }

    _sendLoginInfo(credential, response.success);

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: what is your ParseUser code? and what database do you use?

Comment: @Texv I use mongodb

`class UserModel {

  final ParseUser parseUser;
  final String deviceId;
  final String? referredBy;

  UserModel(this.parseUser, this.deviceId, this.referredBy);

  static UserModel fromParse(ParseUser parseUser) {
    String cityCode = '${CityData.cityCode}';

    String deviceId = parseUser.get<String>(DbKeys.deviceId + cityCode) ?? '';

    String? referredBy = parseUser.get<String>(DbKeys.referredBy);

    return UserModel(parseUser, deviceId, referredBy);
  }


}`

Comment: I don't have experience with mongoDB but I think you just need to use a different signup logic where you store userEmail, userMainId, userFacebookId? (nullable), userGoogleId?, etc and so when you sign up or sign in you make a function that checks if id exist with that email, and if it does then fetch the main ID, then you can load any data using the main id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is a functionality called [linking users](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#linking-users), I didn't find built-in function in [Flutter SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/blob/master/packages/dart/lib/src/objects/parse_user.dart) so I'm attaching docs from REST API.

> Parse allows you to link your users with services like Twitter and Facebook, enabling your users to sign up or log into your application using their existing identities. This is accomplished through the sign-up and update REST endpoints by providing authentication data for the service you wish to link to a user in the `authData` field. Once your user is associated with a service, the `authData` for the service will be stored with the user and is retrievable by logging in.

You're supposed to populate `authData` attribute of user with login provider data in order to link it to the user. This can be done with a help of a cloud code or a simple http request from client. Let's say that you will integrate this in your flutter app the request for linking facebook login provider should be made of:

```bash
# Use PUT http method
curl -X PUT \
  # Add App ID to header
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  # Add Client Key to header
  -H "X-Parse-Client-Key: ${CLIENT_KEY}" \
  # Add Session Token to header of the user you're linking the login provider to
  -H "X-Parse-Session-Token: r:samplei3l83eerhnln0ecxgy5" \
  # Add Contet-Type to header
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "authData": {
          "facebook": {
            "id": "123456789",
            "access_token": "SaMpLeAAibS7Q55FSzcERWIEmzn6rosftAr7pmDME10008bWgyZAmv7mziwfacNOhWkgxDaBf8a2a2FCc9Hbk9wAsqLYZBLR995wxBvSGNoTrEaL",
            "expiration_date": "2022-01-01T12:23:45.678Z"
          }
        }
      }' \
  # Call endpoint for the user you're linking the login provider to
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/parse/users/{user_object_id}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, this kind of works. Now the problem is that I'm using e-mail address to check if user already has created account, but sometimes we cannot get mail using facebook or apple sign in. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I would advise you to define the problem you're facing in a new question. There you can describe the behaviour in more details and I may help you.

Comment: I did what you recommended: [Problem combining multiple login methods into one account for a logged out user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200742/problem-combining-multiple-login-methods-into-one-account-for-a-logged-out-user)